# ClearInterval won't stop timer

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm having trouble stopping a setInterval in javascript, here's my code:

```
    var self = this;
    self.pt = setInterval(function() {
        if (self.startTime <= 0) {
            console.log(self.pt, self.startTime);
            self.updateScore();
            self.updateClock();
            self.showScore();
            clearInterval(self.pt);
        } else {

            self.startTime--;
            self.totalScore++;
            self.updateScore();
            self.updateClock();
        }

    }, 20);
```

The clearInterval gets completely ignored. Any clue?
The console log logs an increasing number and 0, (1234, 0).

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this with a `setTimeout()` and recursion instead of `setInterval()`:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function periodicFunc() {
    if (self.startTime <= 0) {
        console.log(self.startTime);
        self.updateScore();
        self.updateClock();
        self.showScore();
    } else {
        self.startTime--;
        self.totalScore++;
        self.updateScore();
        self.updateClock();
        setTimeout(periodicFunc, 20);
    }
}, 20);
```

See http://www.erichynds.com/blog/a-recursive-settimeout-pattern for further examples and reasons as to why you are better off without `setInterval`.

Also there are no memory issues with `setTimeout` since it places on a queue a function to be run later, but it returns immediately i.e. there is no stack frame waiting around for that function to complete.